# marker at the location (0.0,0.0) in google map direction api

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I try to do an android application and I'm trying to use Google map Direction API to draw line between 2 marker and when I try to decode the polyline point in the JSON I have from goole server I have a bunch of marker set near to the position 0.0,0.0 like in my screenshoot bellow

my polyline decode function is

```
private fun decodePoly(polylineArrayList: ArrayList<String>): List<LatLng> {
    val poly = ArrayList<LatLng>()
    var index = 0
    for (i in 0 until polylineArrayList.size-1) {
        val encoded = polylineArrayList[i]
        val len = encoded.length
        var lat = 0
        var lng = 0

        while (index < len -1) {
            var b: Int
            var shift = 0
            var result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20 )
            val dlat = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lat += dlat

            shift = 0
            result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20 )
            val dlng = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lng += dlng

            val p = LatLng(lat.toDouble() / 1E5,
                    lng.toDouble() / 1E5)
            poly.add(p)
        }
    }
    return poly
}
```

here is the code where i draw the line (i do in in the on success from my asynck task

```
private val options = PolylineOptions()
private val latLongB = LatLngBounds.Builder()
override fun onSuccess(googleDirectionData: GoogleDirectionData?) {
     val polylineArrayList = ArrayList<String>()
     for (route in googleDirectionData?.routes!!) {
          for (leg in route.legs) {
              for (step in leg.steps)
                  polylineArrayList.add(step.polyline.points)
          }
      }
      val polypts = decodePoly(polylineArrayList)
      for (point in polypts) {
          options.add(point)
          latLongB.include(point)
      }
val caisseMarker = LatLng(caisse.wsg84[0], caisse.wsg84[1])
options.add(caisseMarker)
latLongB.include(caisseMarker)
val bounds = latLongB.build()
// add polyline to the map
map.addPolyline(options)
// show map with route centered
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100))
}
```

[bunch of marker near 0.0,0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxXm2.png)

did someone know how to fix this in order 
to no longer have a marker to position 0.0,0.0?